# Series involving arctangent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n - \arctan(\frac1n)$$
Can this sum be calculated (it may involve Gamma or Beta function)?

Maybe both terms of the sum could be replaced by an integral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with :
$$f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac xn - \arctan\left(\frac xn\right)$$

and evaluate first the derivative :
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n - \frac n{n^2+x^2}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n - \frac12\left(\frac 1{n+ix}+\frac 1{n-ix}\right)\\
&=\frac 12(\psi(1+i x)+\psi(1-i x))+\gamma\\
&=\gamma+\Re\,\psi(i x)\\
&=\left(C+\gamma\,x+\Re\,(-i\,\log\Gamma(i x))\right)'\\
&=\left(C+\gamma\,x+\Im\,\log\Gamma(i x)\right)'\\
\end{align}

(using the expressions for the series from [A&S p.$264$ and $265$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_264.htm) and for digamma $\psi(1\pm x)$ in [A&S](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm))

We obtain $f(x)=C+\gamma\,x+\Im\,\log\Gamma(i x)$

with $f(0^+)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\Im\,\log\Gamma(i x)=-\dfrac {\pi}2$ so that $C=\dfrac {\pi}2$ and :
$$f(x)=\frac {\pi}2+\gamma\,x+\Im\,\log\Gamma(i x)$$

Your wished solution will thus be : 
$$\;f(1)=\frac {\pi}2+\gamma+\Im\,\log\Gamma(i)\approx 0.27557534443399966271898$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, consider the contour integral:

$$\oint_{C\left(R\right)}\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}\left[\frac{1}{z}-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right]dz$$

where $C\left(R\right)$ is a counterclockwise circle of radius R. In the limit of R to infinity the integral tends to zero, therefore the sum of the residues must be zero.

Comment: I should find where the function gamma is zero? Thank you!

Comment: The gamma function has poles at the negative integers, the logarithmic derivatives then make these poles with residues equal to minus one. But now you are multiplying this by the function you want to sum over (over the positive integers, but the function is odd so you can also sum over only the negative integers).