# Hard time with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\arctan\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$

Tags: calculus, summation

In the question, I have to prove if it converges (no need to calculate sum) or diverges. I know this is some kind of telescopic series but I can't seem to get a right series to direct compare or in other ways.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\arctan\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$.

Comment: no magic involved. For $0 < x < 1$  the power series for $\arctan x$  is strictly alternating decreasing,  so $  x - \frac{x^3}{3}  < \arctan x < x $  Indeed, $  \frac{2x}{3}  < \arctan x < x $

Comment: Why don't you try see if the terms are positive or not. Also try and compute the limit of the ratio of $\left(\arctan\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ to see if it gives a finite positive number. If so, then what can you conclude by limit comparison test? And no, there are no telescopes involved.

Comment: Write out six to eight of the terms and you will see which types of terms cancel and which terms are left.

Comment: I doubt this converges, the summand approaches zero very slowly.

Comment: It is of course divergent (as $\displaystyle\sum_{n>0} \frac 2n- \frac 1n$ ). To get something convergent you may try $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arctan\left(\frac 2n\right) - \arctan\left(\frac 1n\right)-\frac 1n$ which is $-\gamma-\Im\left(\log\Gamma(2i)-\log\Gamma(i)\right)\approx - 1.00850230167885437\;$ from to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828348/series-involving-arctangent).

Comment: or $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arctan\left(\frac 2n\right) - 2\arctan\left(\frac 1n\right)=\frac {\pi}2-\Im\left(\log\Gamma(2i)-2\log\Gamma(i)\right)\approx  -0.7329269572448547$

Comment: For small x, arctan x ≈ x, so your sum is close to the sum of 2/n - 1/n = 1/n aka harmonic series and divergent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With $f_n(x) =  \arctan\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ and the MVT we know there exists a $\xi_n \in (1,2)$ s.t. $$\arctan\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = f_n(2) - f_n(1) = \frac{f_n(2) - f_n(1)}{2-1} = f_n'(\xi_n) = \frac{n}{n^2 + \xi_n^2}$$
hence for $n > 1$  $$\arctan\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{n}{n^2 + \xi_n^2}\ge  \frac{n}{n^2 + n^2} \ge \frac{1}{2n}$$ and so
$$\sum_{n>1} \left(\arctan\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \ge \sum_{n>1} \frac{1}{2n} = +\infty$$

Comment: clever use of MVT +1

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha_{n} = \arctan(2/n)$ and $\beta_{n} = \arctan(1/n)$. Then one has that:
\begin{align*}
\tan(\alpha_{n} - \beta_{n}) &= \frac{\tan(\alpha_{n}) - \tan(\beta_{n})}{1 + \tan(\alpha_{n})\tan(\beta_{n})} = \frac{1/n}{1 + 2/n^{2}} = \frac{n}{n^{2} + 2} > \frac{1}{2n} \tag{for $n\geq 2$}
\end{align*}
whence one concludes that
\begin{align*}
\alpha_{n} - \beta_{n} > \arctan(1/2n) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(2n) = \operatorname{arccot}(2n) \tag{for $n\geq 2$}
\end{align*}

Consequently, it may be deduced that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq 1}(\alpha_{n} - \beta_{n}) > \sum_{n\geq 2}(\alpha_{n} - \beta_{n}) > \sum_{n\geq 2}\operatorname{arccot}(2n) 
\end{align*}
where the series on the RHS diverges.

Hence the proposed series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Euler-MacLaurin summation
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{n}{n^2+2}\right)=C+\log (p)+\frac{1}{2 p}+\frac{13}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ For this level of expansion
$$C=\frac{1031630128951}{1039500000000}-\frac{1}{2} \log
   \left(\frac{25}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\sim -\frac{2317}{5372}$$

This would give
$$S_{1000} \sim \color{red}{6.4769}459$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is based on
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}{x\over \sin x}=1,$ which implies $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}{x\over \tan x}.$ On substituting $u=\tan x$ we get
$$ \lim_{u\to 0}{ \arctan u\over u}=1$$
Thus
$$\lim_n{\arctan{2\over n}-\arctan {1\over n}\over {1\over n}}=
2\lim_n{\arctan{2\over n}\over {2\over n}}- \lim_n{\arctan{1\over n}\over {1\over n}}=1$$ By the limit test the series is divergent as the series $\sum{1\over n}$ is divergent.